# Autoindent yas-snippets which call up another function

Tags: indentation, yasnippet

I use the snippet `function_docstring_numpy` (shortcut: `fdn`) in python to define nicely documented functions. They look like this:

```
def flip(batch):
    """Flip a batch of images 
    Works for a single image as well as many images, using the Ellipsis object.

Parameters
----------
images : a numpy array with dimensions (num_images, height, width, num_channels)


Returns
-------
out : an array of identical dimensions to input array, with images flipped

    """
    return images[...,::-1,:]
```

I really love this snippet, although that (lack of) indentation of the *Parameters* and *Returns* sections bothers me.

The snippet (show below) call a Lisp function:

```
def ${1:name}($2):
    \"\"\"$3
    ${2:$(python-args-to-docstring-numpy)}
    \"\"\"
    $0
```

I got to the function using `C-x h function_docstring_numpy` and opening the linked function: `python-args-to-docstring-numpy`, which looks like this:

```
(defun python-args-to-docstring-numpy ()
  "return docstring format for the python arguments in yas-text"
  (let* ((args (python-split-args yas-text))
         (format-arg (lambda(arg)
                       (concat (nth 0 arg) " : " (if (nth 1 arg) ", optional") "\n")))
         (formatted-params (mapconcat format-arg args "\n"))
         (formatted-ret (mapconcat format-arg (list (list "out")) "\n")))
    (unless (string= formatted-params "")
      (mapconcat 'identity
                 (list "\nParameters\n----------" formatted-params
                       "Returns\n-------" formatted-ret)
                 "\n"))))
```

I managed to shift the *Returns* sections up a line be removing a newline symbol, but my question is:

#### How can I ensure the entire docstring including *Parameters* and *Returns* are indented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is a simple setting from `YASnippet` itself. In the menu-bar, under `YASnippet`, there is an indentation sub-menu. There are three possibilities: (1) auto (2) fixed (3) none.

This can be set with the menu-bar itself or using a line like this in your init file:

```
(setq yas-indent-line 'auto)    ;; the other option is the value: 'fixed
```

Doing it in the menu bar also persists between sessions.

Comment: That should be `'auto` and `'fixed`. Symbols, not strings.